# Call cms page from custom module

Tags: magento-1.9, module, event-observer, cms, cms-pages

I have created an **event observer** in a module.

Observer is called after `checkout_card_add` event.

I want to **call a cms page** from the module if a certain condition is met.

My `observer.php` file

```
<?php
class Rohan_Module2_Model_Observer
{

            public function changeUserGroup(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
            {

              Mage::log('function entered:');
              $customer1 = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
              $attr = $customer1->getCustomattribute();

                 if(some if conditon about $attr)
                 {
                     //if true redirect to cms page about-us url(http://127.0.0.1/magento1-test/index.php/about-magento-demo-store) 
                 }

             }
}
```

How can i call a **CMS Page** from this `observer.php` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

class Rohan_Module2_Model_Observer
{

    public function changeUserGroup(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {

      Mage::log('function entered:');
      $customer1 = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
      $attr = $customer1->getCustomattribute();

         if(some if conditon about $attr)
         {
            //This will redirect to about-us page
             Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getBaseUrl().'about-us')->sendResponse();
             exit();
         }

     }
}
```